# CDialog Object assigning

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

```
CDialog *m_Dlg = NULL;
m_Dlg = this;
```

What happens if we assign a `CDialog` object to `this`, like in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

It means that `m_Dlg` now points to the class instance which function is currently being executed. It also means that the function is a member of class of type CDialog or derived from it.